# Android view with multiple random animation instances

Tags: java, android, animation

So, I'm working on a main menu activity for my android application.
I want to create background animation where there are things translating from the top of the screen to the bottom.  The x position and translation speed of each will be random (within some limits).

I have created a new thread to run this animation (so the UI doesn't get slow or messed up).
I do not want to use a SurfaceView if possible.  I'm planning on using an ImageView resource, then using .startAnimation(animation), where animation is a translational animation resource.

My problem:

Is it possible for me to create multiple instances of the same ImageView, if I wanted to run multiple animations at the same time (3 of the same ImageViews falling at different rates and different x positions)?

How do I set the starting point of each of the ImageViews to be at some specific x position?  For me to specify an absolute starting point, which type of layout would be required?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've just decided that a linear layout placed on top of a surface view is the best option.  The animation would just be drawn on the surface view while the regular menu interface is contained in the linear layout.

Update:
Used a FrameLayout with a SurfaceView and LinearLayout inside. It works perfectly.

Comment: Did you succeed in it? I'm working on a similar problem, and don't see how to do it. Can you point me in some direction?